# Java: How can I read Reader multiple times?

Tags: java

If I call `IOUtils.toString(reader);` it returns correct string value. Second call returns `""`. Reset does not supported by reader

How can I solve this situation?

Comment: Not all `Reader`s and `InputStream`s have reset capability. Use `bool markSupported()` for reader or `InputStream` to see your input supports it before you can call `reset()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make the `Reader` "re-readable" if it doesn't support `mark()` and `reset()`. But you could use the `String` returned from the call you've shown to create a `StringReader` any number of times, and read those as needed (or use `mark()` and `reset()` on a single instance to re-read it as needed.)

Answer (score 3):

Use a java.io.Reader that does support reset, such as `CharArrayReader` (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayReader.html).

A [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#reset%28%29) also supports reset() of a limited number of characters if a mark is set.

More generally the [markSupported](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#markSupported()) method indicates whether the implementation of Reader you are using supports mark/reset (thanks to comment from Bala R pointing that out).

Comment: there is also a limit to the number of characters that you can reset to, based on the buffering size of the BufferedReader.